# Join data from two arrays

Tags: ios

i created two arrays from API whit different values (6764 records). In first array are codes of states and in second array are name of airports. 
For example: 
Array1: YNL, YLN, CZE etc.
Array2: Airport China, Yeloing Airport, Czech Republic Airport etc.

Knows everybody, please, how join these data?

I need to convert these arrays to one array or string.
Output format will be "YNL - Airport China", "YLN - Yeloing Airport", "CZE - Czech Republic"

I am playing with this over 5hours and i don't know how fix it..

Thank you for help.

Comment: User is not asking for code golf...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very easy problem to solve. You just have to break it down (although it can't get much smaller).

1. How to join two strings together...

   ```
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", firstString, secondString];
   ```
2. How to iterate two arrays...

   ```
   for (int i=0 ; i<array.count ; ++i) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
3. How to get something out of an array...

   ```
   NSString *string = someArray[0];
   ```
4. How to put something into an array...

   ```
   [someArray addObject:someObject];
   ```

Now put them together...

```
NSArray *array1 = ...
NSArray *array2 = ...

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0 ; i<array1.count ; ++i) {
    NSString *string1 = array1[i];
    NSString *string2 = array2[i];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", string1, string2];

    [results addObject:string];
}

NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

`results` will then contain the strings you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want swift solution:

```
let codes = ["A", "B", "C"]
let names = ["Alex", "Ben", "Chuck"]

let result = zip(codes, names).map {
  $0.0+ " - " + $0.1
}
print(result)
```

`zip(codes, names)` will return a sequence of tuples containing 2 strings and we concatenate them in map function.

Comment: I had a 50/50 choice so went for Obj-C. I guess we'll find out which language they are working in soon :) Although, going by the OPs previous questions, probably not.